# Oracle SQL find unique id by date

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, exists

**Hello Experts**,

I am running Oracle 12c on Windows.
I have made a query to find any new id's and the date they were entered.  I wanted to know how you would change the query to include an exact date as part of the search instead of just scanning all the date records on the table.
My query:

```
select carid, inventory_date from car_source t where not exists
      (select carid from car_source t2 where t.carid = t2.carid and t.inventory_date != t2.inventory_date);
```

Table build:

```
CREATE TABLE "CAR_SOURCE" 
   (    "COUNT_CARS" NUMBER(10,0), 
   "EQUIPMENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
   "LOCATION" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
   "INVENTORY_DATE" DATE, 
   "COUNT_INVENTORY" VARCHAR2(3000 BYTE), 
   "CARID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Insert the rows:

```
    Insert into CAR_SOURCE    (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID)    values (3,'Trans AM','London',to_date('04-JUL-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0001');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (5,'Chevy Volt','London',to_date('30-AUG-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0002');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (6,'Trans AM','coventry',to_date('07-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0001');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (5,'Chevy Volt','coventry',to_date('02-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0002');
 Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (8,'Rovers','coventry',to_date('07-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0003');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (9,'Jaguars','coventry',to_date('07-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0004');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (7,'Rovers','London',to_date('30-AUG-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0003');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (10,'Escalade','London',to_date('17-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0005');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (12,'Mustangs','London',to_date('11-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0006');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (2,'Trans AM','Brummy',to_date('20-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0001');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (5,'Limo','London',to_date('12-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0007');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (2,'Lambo','Essex',to_date('19-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0008');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (1,'Limo','London',to_date('19-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0007');
Insert into CAR_SOURCE (COUNT_CARS,EQUIPMENT_TYPE,LOCATION,INVENTORY_DATE,COUNT_INVENTORY,CARID) values (2,'Chevy Volt','London',to_date('19-SEP-19','DD-MON-RR'),null,'0002');
```

Results:

- carid   DATE
     0004    07-SEP-19
     0005    17-SEP-19
     0006    11-SEP-19
     0008    19-SEP-19

Let's say I wanted to query for a particular date '19-SEP-19', would I create an alias for the first query and join it to a second date query?
Any advice on how to pull this together would be very helpful.
Kindest regards,
Gilly

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find ids entered on a particular date, you can use aggregation:

```
select car_id
from car_source
group by car_id
having min(inventory_date) = date '2019-09-19';
```

`EXISTS` is useful if you want all the records in the table.  However, if you just want the `car_id`s first entered on that date, then aggregation is a simple approach.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I was looking to discover any unique(new id's) on a particular day that have not existed before on the table.

Comment: Ahh, thanks again Gordon.  I understand that I cannot find the result I am looking for, I need to scan the entire table for new id's.  My logic would not work to gather the new id's from just 1 day- I would need to scan all records to ensure that the id is new.

Comment: @Gilly . . . That is what this code does.  It returns the ids that appear first on the specified date.